# A page as a Panorama item

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I have a single Windows Phone page, let say Details.xaml. 
I want to use it as a single view page as well as to reuse that page in different panorama pages.

How can I add that page as an PanoramaItem?

Can you provide some go resource about good practice in implementing Panorama page in Windows Phone 8?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) containing the Visual structure that you wish to present, you can check the microsoft [guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202912%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) on Panorama pages.